# difference of two xml files python

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

1. If I have two XML files with the same tags but different attributes and texts values. I have tried xmldiff but I did not know how to use it in my project.
   I need to extract the differences in the attributes and the values to new XML structure.
   In my code I tried to compare every node with all the other nodes but if the other file have sub elements with the same name multiple times this code does not work.

My code:

```
walkAll = tree1.getiterator()
for  elt in walkAll:
    el=root2.find(elt.tag)
    for ee in root2.iter(elt.tag):
        p1=ee.getparent()
        p2=el.getparent()
        if p1==p2:
            if ee.text !=elt.text:
                print(ee.text+"****"+elt.text )
```

2. How can I get the direct  first order parent to an xml node?

Comment: also ee.getparent() does not work